# Closing a SerialPort instance inside a class

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have created a library class for a control circuit which communicates through a serial port and is used in WinForms. When the class is initialized the serial port is opened

```
CircuitController controller = new CircuitController("Controller1", COM8, Baud9600, ...);
```

But what is the appropriate way to close the serial port when I exit the WinForm application? Should this be called on the controller specifically

```
(On close) --> controller.Shutdown();
```

Or will the serial port automatically close when the Form is closed?

Comment: The proper idiom would be to make your class implement `IDisposable`, and dispose your class when your form is disposed.

Comment: @ildjarn, You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @Brad : I don't want to get sucked into answering C# questions. ;-] Feel free to post it as an answer, I'll upvote it.

Comment: @ildjarn, Ha, okay.  Done, but mainly because nobody else was posting it, and you definitely have the right answer here.  I'd rather be up-voting you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per ildjarn's suggestion:

The best thing to do here is implement `IDisposable`, and close your port there.  You can find some excellent example code for doing this on MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the port will close when the program exits (all handles opened by a process are closed by the os when the process exits as far as I understand), but I'm sure most will agree that it is best practice to close the port explicitly, as per your first suggestion.

Comment: Or even better, as per @ildjarn's suggestion